# How to store path names in a string in C?

Tags: c

```
argv[1]=argv[1]/filenames[j]

argv[1]=folder1
and filenames[2]=cool
```

I want to store folder1/cool in argv[1]
 how to proceed?
I am not familiar with C.

Comment: What platform? It matters when determining the largest allowable size of a path name.

Comment: If your not familiar with C, in which way will the answer help you?

Comment: I am using ubuntu. I am not familiar with C, but I am familiar with the logic. I got everything working except for this part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. you should be using `"folder1"` and `"cool"` if these are litterals
2. you should use `strcat(str1, str2)` if you want to mimmic `str1 = str1 + str2` of e.g. Java
3. you might prefer `sprintf(str1, "%s/%s","folder","cool")`
4. none of the above is correct unless `str1` is an array of char that has enough room to store the result (welcome to C)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That really helped. I am really embarrassed asking such a noob question.

Comment: char holder[xxx]; snprintf(holder, xxx, "%s/%s", basename, filename);

that would be my favourite way to handle something alike unless the content of "holder" needs to have a wider scope than the current function.

Comment: @sylvainulg: actually, if you `char holder[BIGNUM]` you can just use `sizeof(holder) - 1`. Btw, you shall never forget to handle the trailing `'\0'`unless you wanto to experience some interesting things when using `%s` (as you said, welcome to C)

Comment: @steve schnepp: sure, we don't want to see the terminating "\0" to be placed outside of holder[]. However, according to my documentation of `snprintf(str, size, format, ...)`, the functions write at most `size` bytes (including the trailing null byte) to str. So `snprintf(holder, BIGNUM, "%s/%s", ...)` should be correct for a conforming implementation.

Comment: @sylvainulg: +1, actually you're quite right, sorry. [ As a matter of fact, thanks to you, I just realized that I was wrong, and too conservative all this years... (sic) ]